# How to use bootstrap popover in angular 7 using jquery?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, angular7, popover

I am trying to implement bootstrap4 popover using jquery in angular7. I have included "popper.js" in index.html and included using npm too. but it's not working.

> Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).popover is not a function

this error only appears in the console.

HTML:(sample.component.html)

```
<button id="option2" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="popover"> Public</button>
```

Jquery: (sample.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }   
  ngOnInit() {   
    $(document).ready(function(){   
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();     
      $('#option2').popover({
         html: true,
        content: function() {
          return $("#div").html();
        },
         placement: 'bottom'
      });            
    });
  }
```

How to achieve bootstrap popover in angular 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Attention**: using jQuery in Angular is not a good practice as @ErikHer implied. The interesting thing in this case is to use the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) library, which is a library developed in the angular standards with the elements Bootstrap 4 or less. Also you can use Bootstrap 5, where they stopped using jQuery.

Anyway, the method below works, but it is not recommended.

Thank you @ErikHer for making the answer more complete.

---

Change your component file to that way:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any; // ADD THIS
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }   
  ngOnInit() {   
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  }
```

You don't need use `$(document).ready()` because the `NgOnInit()` do the same thing.
And the `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` will start all Popover you have in your component.

You can use title, data-placement and data-content attributes for make the Popover like:

```
<button id="option2" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="popover's title" data-content="popover's text"> Public</button>
```

Or you can initialize the popover with the function that you used in `NgOnInit()`:

```
$('#option2').popover({
         html: true,
        content: function() {
          return $("#div").html();
        },
         placement: 'bottom'
      });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: please, don't use jQuery in Angular :( :(